# PDO php echo field based on another field value

Tags: php, select, pdo

How can I echo a field based on the value of another field?
I hope my script can tell you somehow what I want.

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE item = '$item'");
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo ($row['amount'] WHERE $row['currency'] = 'USD');
```

[image: You can see how the currency is displayed as data fields here]

This is the script I have created from your ideas.. But it still makes no sense to me that it has to be this stupid. The bottom script with $pdf you can just ignore.

```
foreach($conn->query("SELECT amount FROM stockpricetable WHERE itemrelation = '$row[itemnumber]'") as $row2) {
    if ($row2['exchange'] == '') { $DKK = $row2['amount'];}
    if ($row2['exchange'] == 'CHF') { $CHF = $row2['amount'];}
    if ($row2['exchange'] == 'EUR') { $EUR = $row2['amount'];}
    if ($row2['exchange'] == 'GBP') { $GBP = $row2['amount'];}
    if ($row2['exchange'] == 'SEK') { $SEK = $row2['amount'];}
    if ($row2['exchange'] == 'USD') { $USD = $row2['amount'];}
}
    $pdf->Text(26, 4, 'DKK'.$DKK);
    $pdf->Text(26, 8, 'EUR'.$EUR);
    $pdf->Text(26, 12, 'GBP'.$GBP);
    $pdf->Text(46, 4, 'SEK'.$SEK);
    $pdf->Text(46, 8, 'CHF'.$CHF);
    $pdf->Text(46, 12, 'USD'.$USD);
```

Comment: echo is not sql no where clause

Comment: Try to see my update.. maybe you understand what I am looking for...

Comment: wasnt it solved below in answers. didnt Denis solve it?

Comment: it returns mistakes.. but probably caused by other scripting..

Comment: ok so you have an item u are seeking on. what are you trying to echo. your question kinda changed. do you want USD row only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should just be a case of:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE item = '$item'");
$sth->execute();
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

if ($row['currency'] == 'USD') {
    echo $row['amount'];
}
```

Although, this is assuming the code above the if statement fetches the database results correctly, I can't tell as ashamedly, I still use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

That is problem to traverse entire result?

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   if ($row["currency"] == "USD") echo $row["amount"];
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. the thing is that I have 6 different currencies, but they are written as data in fields instead of column names.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 if (strstr($row["amount"], 'USD) !== FALSE) 
   echo $row["amount"];
}
```